# UIScrollView zoomScale not updating after initial update

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a tap gesture that runs this code and it works once but then stops updating the `zoomScale`.

```
@objc func sampleTapGestureTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapped")
    if self.scrollView_Image.zoomScale > self.scrollView_Image.minimumZoomScale {
        scrollView_Image.setZoomScale(1, animated: false)
    } else {
        scrollView_Image.setZoomScale(3, animated: false)
    }
}
```

The function runs and the `tapped` print is logged out but the zoomScale doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Where is that code and what does the action do?

Comment: I have written it in viewWillAppear. Double tapping the imageView zooms in picture but it is called only once.

Comment: Can you show us the code within `@objc func sampleTapGestureTapped(..){...}`?

Comment: productimageView is destroyed and recreated again possibly?

Comment: Have you added a `print` log to check the function is actually running? Please add all this extra code to the question by editing the question. It is all relevant.

Comment: I added print statement to check if its been executed, and its executing as expected. I think there's something wrong after that. Trying to figure that out

Comment: So the selector does respond. It’s the logic that is flawed then?

Comment: Yes I believe its the logic for zoom

Comment: I just updated the question. Please make sure you provide all the relevant information when writing questions and that you've done at least a little debugging yourself. It helps a lot to avoid confusion amongst those trying to help you solve your problem. :)

Comment: But the zoom statements are executing only for once and tapped is print only once.  sampleTapGestureTapped is not getting called when double tapped again.

Comment: That exactly contradicts what you wrote earlier. Pick one either the function is called many times or it is only called once. Which is it.

Comment: If I write only print statement, it gets called every time. However, when I write print along with zoom code, it gets called only once. Somehow gesture is getting removed when zoom statements are called once.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is your hard coded numbers. Here is how I do it:

```
    if sv.zoomScale < sv.maximumZoomScale {
        sv.setZoomScale(sv.maximumZoomScale, animated:anim)
    }
    else {
        sv.setZoomScale(sv.minimumZoomScale, animated:anim)
    }
```

Notice there are no hard coded numbers here. It works for any scroll view.

Comment: I have used your code exactly but print statement is executing only once. It doesn't invoke it when its double tapped again. It is just executing for once

Comment: OK, then something else must be going on. But you have not told us what it is. Earlier you said "I added print statement to check if its been executed, and its executing as expected". So I assumed your action handler is always called. There is nothing about my code that would change that; I'm just suggesting you change those lines. My `sv` is your `scrollView_Image`.

Comment: Thats if I only use print statement, it gets invoked every time. However, when I used zoom code (as you suggested above) below print statement, it gets called only once and stop getting invoked after that.

Comment: Well I can’t explain that. You must be doing something that removes the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this in a small View Controller and it is working fine. It is possible that an action you are taking in the selector is stopping the gesture from working. You should probably post the selector function code as well, and anything relevant to setting up the Recognizer and the Image View

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tappableImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tappableImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 100, height: 100))
        tappableImageView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(tappableImageView)
        tappableImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageViewDoubleTapped(_:)))
        t.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        tappableImageView.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }

    @objc func imageViewDoubleTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Double Tapped")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP's question here was not actually about the tap gesture recogniser. I have updated the question to highlight the actual issue they were having.